# it is not showing the output, the screen is blank white

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio, mobile-application

[image]

it is not showing the output, the screen is blank white. what should i do? please answer me as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

When you use react-navigation then you have to uninstall the app and kill the terminal and re run the app then it will work fine.

Comment: It's not about react navigation only, it's about any node module which gets installed - especially the one, that requires the corresponding native module. The app should be rebuilt so the JS bundle gets regenerated - in order to use the newly installed module.